# how to update view with list of items in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that displays a list of items and it has a search function.
The first time a user displays the page the page displays all items.

If they enter text in a search box and hit submit, the page calls an action that retrieves, from a database, a new list of items to be displayed on the page.

Here's my full controller. The very last line is where I'm not sure how to pass my params and if this is even the right way to go about it.

```
public IActionResult Index(IEnumerable<ItemListingModel> searchResults)
{
    var categoryNames = _assets.GetCategoryNames();
    var marketNames = _assets.GetMarketCategoryNames();
    if (!searchResults.Any())
    {
        var assetItems = _assets.GetAll();
        searchResults = assetItems.Select(result => new ItemListingModel
        {
            Id = result.Id,
            ImageUrl = result.ImageUrl,
            Title = result.Title,
            Category = result.Category.Name,
            Sku = result.Sku,
            Location = result.Location,
            Available = result.Available,
            Notes = result.Notes
        });
    }

    var assetModel = new ItemIndexModel()
    {
        Items = searchResults,
        Categories = categoryNames,
        Markets = marketNames
    };

    var searchForm = new SearchFormModel()
    {
        SearchQuery = "Enter search query"
    };

    ViewModel myModel = new ViewModel();
    myModel.Item1 = assetModel;
    myModel.Item2 = searchForm;
    return View(myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SearchSubmit(ViewModel search)
{
    var results = _assets.searchInventoryAssets(search.Item2.SearchQuery, search.Item2.CategoryName, search.Item2.MarketCategoryName, search.Item2.ColumnName, search.Item2.ValueExpression).Select(result => new ItemListingModel
    {
        Id = result.Id,
        ImageUrl = result.ImageUrl,
        Title = result.Title,
        Category = result.Category.Name,
        Sku = result.Sku,
        Location = result.Location,
        Available = result.Available,
        Notes = result.Notes
    });

    return //update index View with results list from this function, how can I achieve this? 
}
```

Comment: You can just `return(results)` or `return(results, "TheNameOfYourView")` but it's not the best method. The correct approach is to follow the [PRG](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/) pattern when you're doing a traditional POST.

Comment: In your case, since it is just a search, PRG may not be needed.

Comment: What do you mean return (results)?  You mean change my searchSubmit from returning an IActionResult to just returning a list?

Comment: Sorry I meant `return View(results)` or `return View(results, "TheNameOfYourView)`.

Comment: o got it ! thanks!. using   search.Item1 = createItemIndexModel(results);
            return View("Index", search);

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note about coding standard: `ViewModel` is not a good name, I suggest renaming this class to `SearchQueryViewModel`

---

Why are you using `HttpPost` for your `Search` method?

We use `HttpPost` for sending data to the server and normally we want to persist this data... we can also send data to the server using `QueryString` in the URL, using `HttpGet`.

It depend on your application but generally it is better to send the search parameters in the `QueryString` instead of posting them in a form. The reason is:

If you use `QueryString`, then your url would look like:

```
www.myDomain/search?Item1=xyz&Item2=abc
```

This means your user can copy the above url and paste in an email and send it to his friend... the friend can click on the above url and he would see the same result.

But, currently you cannot do this, your url is always: `www.myDomain/search` and the search parameters are being passed through the form.

Again, it depend on your application, but if you want to change your code, it would look like this:

```
// remove [HttpPost] and use HttpGet request
public IActionResult Search(SearchQueryViewModel searchQuery)
{
    // do youe search and get the result
    var searchResult = MySearchService.Search(searchQuery);

    // here DisplaySearchResult is the name of the view which displays the search result 
     return View(searchResult, "DisplaySearchResult")
}
```

---

Also, your `Index` action method does not look right to me... in MVC, Controller would build the Model and then pass this Model to the View. In case of your `Index` action, you are passing the `searchResults` to the `Index` method... you have already built the search results in another controller, they should be passed to the View not to another controller. Your current `Index` method is essentially a mapper, which does not seem right to me.

Comment: o interesting never thought if that way. Yeah a querystring might be better.